# Is it possible to calculate the inverse Laplace transform of the following?

Tags: integral-transforms

I have a Laplace tranform in the form given below

$\mathcal{L}_I(s)=\text{exp}(-\pi\lambda \Gamma(1+\frac{2}{\alpha})\Gamma(1-\frac{2}{\alpha})P^{2/\alpha}s^{2/\alpha})$

Can some one help me to find the inverse Laplace transform of it?

Here, $\alpha$ can take values like 1,2,3,4,5...

$P$ and $\lambda$ are constants.

Note: for $\alpha=4$, there exists a closed-form solution. How about for general values of $\alpha$.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! First take the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e. its about mathematics and not Mathematica. If that's not your intenetion, please [edit] your question to make it explicitly about Wolfram Mathematica programming. Include a [formatted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) minimum example of the code you are working on. What have you tried so far?

Comment: An identity that might help you: $$\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac1{\mathrm{sinc}\,\pi x}$$

Comment: If I am right, after rescaling you can just focus on $\exp(-s^\beta)$.

Comment: Dimitrios stop posting the same question 5 times http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658428/find-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-the-following   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657916/how-to-find-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-the-following and on mathoverflow and ...

Comment: @ Dimitrios did you try what I proposed: expanding $\exp(-A s^{2/\alpha})$ and inverse Laplace transforming each term ?

Comment: This inverse LT is discussed in my Quora contribution:  https://qr.ae/pvBtNI.  The function is a Laplace transform if and only if 0<2/alpha<1.  There are two values of alpha for which the inverse LT is explicity known: alpha=4 and alpha=6.  For other values the inverse LT can be expressed as a Meijer G function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you some solutions for $\alpha$. For general values of $\alpha$ is impossible to solve.Maybe someone smarter to solve this in the future. :)

Now we simplify to: $\mathcal{L}_I(s)=\text{exp}(-{A} s^{2/\alpha})$

**where** $A = \pi\lambda \Gamma(1+\frac{2}{\alpha})\Gamma(1-\frac{2}{\alpha})P^{2/\alpha}$ and $A > 0$

for $\alpha = 1$ is Infinity.

for $\alpha = 2$ is $0$.

for $\alpha = 3$

where 
$\text{AiryAi}$ is Airy function,$\text{AiryAiPrime}$ is derivative of the Airy function.

$$\frac{2 A e^{-\frac{2 A^3}{27 t^2}} \left(\sqrt[3]{3} A \text{Ai}\left(\frac{A^2}{3 \sqrt[3]{3} t^{4/3}}\right)-3 t^{2/3} \text{Ai}'\left(\frac{A^2}{3
   \sqrt[3]{3} t^{4/3}}\right)\right)}{3\ 3^{2/3} t^{7/3}}$$

for $\alpha = 4$

$$\frac{A e^{-\frac{A^2}{4 t}}}{2 \sqrt{\pi } t^{3/2}}$$

for $\alpha = 5$

where $_1F_3$ is the generalized hypergeometric function.
$$\frac{A \left(120 \sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}} t^{6/5} \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{5}\right) \, _1F_3\left(\frac{7}{10};\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};-\frac{4 A^5}{3125
   t^2}\right)+A \left(A \left(5 \sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}} A \Gamma \left(\frac{13}{5}\right) \,
   _1F_3\left(\frac{13}{10};\frac{6}{5},\frac{7}{5},\frac{8}{5};-\frac{4 A^5}{3125 t^2}\right)-24 \sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}} t^{2/5} \Gamma \left(\frac{6}{5}\right)
   \, _1F_3\left(\frac{11}{10};\frac{4}{5},\frac{6}{5},\frac{7}{5};-\frac{4 A^5}{3125 t^2}\right)\right)-48 \sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}} t^{4/5} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{4}{5}\right) \, _1F_3\left(\frac{9}{10};\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{6}{5};-\frac{4 A^5}{3125 t^2}\right)\right)\right)}{240 \sqrt{2} \pi 
   t^{13/5}}$$

for $\alpha = 6$

$$\frac{A \text{Ai}\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt[3]{3} \sqrt[3]{t}}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{3} t^{4/3}}$$

**Mathematica code:**

for $\alpha \in integers$ and  $\alpha > 0$

```
 \[Alpha] = 4;
 f[s_] := Exp[-A*s^(2/\[Alpha])]; 
 F = Assuming[{A > 0, t > 0, {t, A} \[Element] Reals},Integrate[f[s]*Exp[s*t] /. s -> I*y, {y, 0, Infinity}]/Pi]; 
 FullSimplify[ComplexExpand@Re[F], {t > 0, A > 0, {t, A} \[Element] Reals}]
```

A similar solution I'm found in the [Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120598760), page: 1012, example: 15.12.2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, when I type your code in mathematica, it just gives me {y,-infinity,+infinity}.  And why the integration is divided by Pi?

Comment: My code is working, I checked numericall.If not working You must Clear all  values and definitions or reload kernel.Why is divided by Pi-> thats why see: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BromwichIntegral.html

Comment: @I_Marisuz, thanks for your answer. My question was why Pi, why not 2Pi. is it because you only consider the real part!

Comment: Because we have rotated the line of integration through 90° (by
using(s = I*y -> ds = I dy). The path has become an infinite vertical line in the complex plane, the constant γ having been chosen so that all the singularities of f(s) are on the left-hand side.

Comment: @Dimitrios .Now the answer is more clearer.

Comment: Thanks for editing. What is the reason for this editing. The previous solutions were not correct? Can you provide the solutions in latex format as before.

Comment: @Dimitrios.Previous solutions was correct.I'm found way to simplify solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It works very well. Let F be the output of the abovementioned code, where F is a function of t. Now I want to perform M = Integrate[t*Exp[-x*t]*F, {t, 0, \Infinity}], it does not work! It gives some syntax error. What should I do?

Comment: You can  solved this integral numerically.MMA can't solve Symbolicall.